# How to make a TextView height fill the screen and position an image next to a list view

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I am trying to figure out a couple issues with a layout and hope someone with layout knowledge can help. I have the xml below with a screenshot of ultimately what I am trying to achieve plus a screenshot of what the xml currently will show.

1) In the center section (lorem ipsum text in the screen shot) I need to have the height fill the screen.  Basically I am trying to have that section expand such that it pushes the offices text and the items below it down.

2) In the bottom section I have two image buttons to scroll left and right and the listview in the middle. I cannot figure out how to have the right image button appear to the right of the list view.

Here is the xml and screenshot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivPhoto"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivPhoto" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPracticeName"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivPhoto"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvName" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPracticeType"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivPhoto"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvPracticeName" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivFacebook"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvPracticeType"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivPhoto"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivFacebook"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvPracticeType"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivPhoto"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivLinkedIn"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvPracticeType"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivFacebook"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivTwitter"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvPracticeType"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivLinkedIn"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
        <TextView
            android:text="This section needs to growth vertically as to push the offices down."
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:text="Offices"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivLeftScroll"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvOffices"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivLeftScroll" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivRightScroll"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

￼This is ultimately what I want to achieve, I can do the styling, I just need help with the two questions above:

[image]

Below is what the xml produces:

[image]

Thanks for the help!!

*** UPDATE: I updated the xml and made the last section a relative layout and also changed the ListView width to 0dp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code, it should work also its not a good idea to set `ListView` height to `wrap_content` so I am setting it to 120dp, set an appropriate value for your purpose:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:minWidth="25px" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPhoto"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivPhoto"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPracticeName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivPhoto"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPracticeType"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvPracticeName"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivPhoto"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivFacebook"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvPracticeType"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivPhoto"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivFacebook"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvPracticeType"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivPhoto"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivLinkedIn"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvPracticeType"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivFacebook"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivTwitter"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvPracticeType"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivLinkedIn"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Growing section"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Offices"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivLeftScroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvOffices"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivRightScroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I updated the post with modified xml.  I made your change and also made the layout that the list view is in a relative layout.  That may fix the list view question #2 above.

Comment: What? I have answered you question. Have you tried my answer? I solved both of your questions. Please accept it as an answer or tell me if something is still missing. Don't update your question with my answer.

Comment: LOL, Sorry!!  I did not see where you answered #1... does making the height 0dp do that?

Comment: yes making height 0dp and setting weight to 1, I solved your 1st answer. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes it seems to work... at least in the designed.  I am adding code to use the layout now so I will now for sure a bit later.  Thank you for the help!!

Comment: M-WaJeEh - FYI, it works great!!!  I do have an additional question about the layout though.  I also need to add a gradient behind the Growing Section all the way down to the bottom of the screen.  I am trying to add a layout behind all those controls so that I can apply my gradient to it.  But when I place a LinearLayout and then put everything beneath the grow section it gets messed up. Any suggestions how to do it?